# How can I make this top nav open downward and to the right so my items don't get covered up?

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, responsive

I'm trying to finish this multi level top nav but I'm having trouble understanding how to make the "Super Submenu" items show on the RIGHT of the "Submenu" items. You'll notice at current state, they appear below and anything that's not the last item is of course being covered up. I've tried adjusting the CSS but I keep getting myself confused when it's likely something quite simple. I've also considered rebuilding this using more javascript to control visibility but that seems overkill.

Here is my html and css:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

li {
    color: #fff;
  background: rgb(29, 39, 87);
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: 1rem;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
  
li a {
  color: #fff;
}

li:hover,
li:focus-within {
    background: #cc1f2e;
    cursor: pointer;
}

li:focus-within a {
  outline: none;
}

ul li ul {
    background: rgb(29, 39, 87);
    visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  min-width: 5rem;
    position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin-top: 1rem;
    left: 0;
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover > ul,
ul li:focus-within > ul,
ul li ul:hover,
ul li ul:focus {
   visibility: visible;
   opacity: 1;
   display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
    clear: both;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```
<nav role="navigation">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" aria-haspopup="true">Item 2</a>
      <ul class="dropdown" aria-label="submenu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a>
          <ul class="dropdown2">
            <li><a href="#">Super Submenu 1</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a>
          <ul class="dropdown2">
            <li><a href="#">Super Submenu 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Item 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I have a test bed here: https://codepen.io/holmesrm23/pen/MWZBLym

Comment: Nothing works... You must update your code for a [minimal & reproducible one](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), As it is recommanded in [SO guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: oops! I did it wrong. will do